# Continuous non-vanishing vector field on annulus shape regions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, vector-fields

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open bounded region and $\Omega_0 \subset \subset \Omega$. Assume also that $\Omega_0$ is simply-connected. Suppose a continuous non-vanishing vector field $F$ is defined on $(\Omega \backslash \Omega_0 )^c$. Can $F$ be extended to a continuous non-vanishing vector field $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: why not? see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem

Comment: @daw Thank you for your comment. Tietze extension theorem works for real valued function. Here we have a vector valued function, say $F=(f_1,f_2)$. The real valued functions $f_1, f_2$ each may be zero on ($\Omega \backslash \Omega_0)^c$, but not at the same time. How can we guarantee that $F=(f_1, f_2)$ does not vanish in our extension to $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Comment: miss the non-vanishing part. Then the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem should help to construct a counterexample

Comment: Do you mean for $F$ to extend to a continuous non-vanishing vector field on $\Omega$  or all of $\mathbb R^2$? As it stands it is not clear why you need to phrase things in terms of the pair $(\Omega_0, \Omega)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure of exactly what your hypotheses are supposed to be, but does this give a counterexample?

Take $\Omega_0 = \{x\in\mathbb R^2: 1<\|x\|<2\}$ and $\Omega= B(0,2) = \{x \in \mathbb R^2: \|x\|<2\}$ and $F(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}(x_2,-x_1)$. The $\Omega\backslash \Omega_0 = \{x\in \mathbb R^2: \|x\|\leq 1\}$, and $F$ is defined on all of $\{x\in \mathbb R^2: \|x\|>1\} = (\Omega\backslash \Omega_0)^c$, but clearly $F$ cannot be extended continuously to a function $
\tilde{F}\colon \Omega \to \mathbb R^2$ since $\lim_{x \to 0} F(x)$ does not exist.

**Update**

For any $a \in \mathbb R^2$ let $F_a(x)= F(x-a)$ where $F(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}(x_2,-x_1)$ is as above. Then the vector field $F_a$ is smooth on $\mathbb R^2 \backslash \{a\}$ but cannot be extended to a continuous vector field at $a$. It follows that if $\Omega_0 \subset\subset \Omega$ and we pick $a=(a_1,a_2) \in \Omega\backslash\Omega_0$, then the vector field $F_a(x)$ is defined on $(\Omega\backslash \Omega_0)^c$ and cannot be extended to all of $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that $\Omega_0$ is simply connected, so $\Omega \backslash \Omega_0$ is topologically an annulus shape region. Do you think there would be a counter-example?

Comment: I think the vector field I used gives you counterexamples -- see the update in my answer.